# Unable to bind click event to an echoed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bind

In JS I fire up a PHP script via XHR which is supposed to do:

```
 if($update)
    echo "<div class='popup'><div>(some text)</div></div>.";

echo "<script> $(document).ready(function() { $('.popup').bind('click', function() {   $('.popup').hide(); }); }); </script>"
```

I think I've tried everything, but there's no way I can make `.popup` hide after click. Where should I put `.bind` handler for this to work?

Comment: It should work like you have it: http://jsfiddle.net/9cCZ3/. Do you get any errors on the console?

Answer (score 1):

First add jQuery script to your JavaScript file which is common for all pages or whatever you want.

for e.g:

```
// Put this to main.js script file
jQuery(document).on('click', 'div[data-rel=popup]', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

And echo your HTML as:

```
if($update)
    echo "<div class='popup' data-rel='popup'><div>(some text)</div></div>.";
```